# Gremlin command history doesn't work in titan 1.0.0

Tags: titan, gremlin

Just got Titan 1.0.0 and in the windows gremlin console the command history doesn't work.

How can i fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the gremlin.bat file add to the set JAVA_OPTIONS line:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms32m -Xmx512m -javaagent:%LIBDIR%\jamm-0.3.0.jar
```

add:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms32m -Xmx512m -javaagent:%LIBDIR%\jamm-0.3.0.jar -Djline.terminal=none
```

[source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-console/src/main/bin/gremlin.bat#L38)